# using cURL to auto fill and submit the form

Tags: php, forms, curl, webforms

I am trying to auto fill and submit the form using cURL, the code is here but it is doing absolutely nothing,

```
<?php
$post_data['countryID'] = '162';
$post_data['autocomplete'] = 'Assam, Karimganj';
$post_data['state'] = '3007';
$post_data['city'] = '60695';
$post_data['countryStateCityCase'] = '2';
$post_data['usesAutoComplete'] = '1';
$post_data['categoryParent'] = '185';
$post_data['categoryChild'] = '219';
$post_data['listing_type'] = '2';
$post_data['title'] = 'Title goes here';
$post_data['currency_typeC'] = '13';
$post_data['priceC'] = '2500';
$post_data['description']= 'Descriptio goes hereDescriptio goes hereDescriptio goes hereDescriptio goes here';
$post_data['email']= 'olx@test.com';
$post_data['ad_language_id']= '1';
$post_data['identity']= '1';
$post_data['imageQty']= '0';
$post_data['phone']= '03311234567';
$post_data['bddisclaimer']= '0';
$post_data['security_code']= 'undefined';
$post_data['captchaKey']= 'undefined';
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
echo $post_string;
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('http://www.olx.in/posting.php?src=8');

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo $result;
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

curl_close($curl_connection);
?>
```

all the fields are properly filled but the nothing is output and i am receiving no confirmation email at all but manually it is working fine, could somebody help me out ?

Comment: Look into the `http_build_query` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reason that hits my head is that you are not doing a [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) while building the content of the HTTP POST request. You can use [urlencode(..)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to encode the value of the key-value pair.

Replace

```
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
```

with:

```
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
```

Comment: Or, better yet, just pass the array to curl_setopt which will build the query for you. Or use http_build_query.